# Incorporating 100VDC Cockcroft–Walton generator onto PCB for biasing PIN diode?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design, high-voltage

I need to deliver 100VDC to reverse bias a PIN diode. I'm currently using a HV DC-DC converter and wiring its output to a screw terminal on my PCB (labeled "Vbias"). However, I'd like to get away from this if possible by creating and delivering the 100VDC directly on the PCB. The first idea I had was using a Cockcroft–Walton generator with x-stages. Though this will take up a lot of space on the board. Are there any other ways of taking 12V and jumping it to 100V that would work well on a PCB?

EDIT: The source voltage is 12VDC, not AC.

[image]

Comment: Try looking at boost converter chips.

Comment: You could, but a small flyback converter might be a better option. It's not as hard to make a dc-dc converter on-board as you might think.

Comment: Almost every photodiode bias circuit I have seen used a boost or similar DCDC converter. I've seen them integrated directly onto APD detectors and fit into ~ 1 square centimeter. Don't reinvent the wheel, use the cheap/easy solution.

Comment: @user1850479: that's an answer, particularly if you can post a schematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At low voltages like 100 V, a Dickson configuration is preferable to a Cockroft Walton, as it has a much lower output impedance.

You have the same diode ladder up to the high voltage output. But instead of each pump capacitor being connected to the previous one, each is connected to the AC source.

This means you can use lower value capacitors for the same output current, but the final ones have to stand the full output voltage, so they may not necessarily be smaller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk1qDz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a push-pull driven one, for making the most of your low DC input voltage. Note the diode string starts from your +12 V rail to save a stage.

A component choice tip, FET driver ICs make excellent drivers for these things. You can get duals, and they deliver peak currents of several amps, swinging rail to rail, take nice logic inputs, and are very small and reasonably inexpensive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I forgot to mention that I am stepping up 12VDC, not AC.

Comment: @TristenLee Of course you're using a DC supply, that's why you need suitable drivers, like FET gate drivers, to drive the antiphase squarewaves into the mulitplier. I'll modify the drawing for those lacking imagination.

Comment: So, CLK1 just represents an AC signal and you're using the initial 12-volt input as a base line of sorts for the voltage multiplier? If the only voltage you're working with is DC, what would you use to generate an appropriate AC voltage?

Comment: @BestQualityVacuum The circuit I've drawn uses AC at 3 points. The first is at the output of CLK1. It could be a 555, it could be the port pin of an MCU. It's a logic level squarewave of suitable frequency to drive the multiplier, and a suitable voltage level to drive the G1/2 buffers, which output the other two AC signals. As I've suggested, G1 and G2 could be FET gate drivers. Most will accept TTL levels in, so 0V low, 3.3 V to 5 V high, and convert that to whatever output supply you give them, most will handle 15 V or more on the output.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you for the clarification. This answers my question more than adequately. Thanks!

Comment: @Neil_UK Would you consider the Dickson configuration to be "low noise, low ripple?" The diode spec sheet specifically recommends this for the bias supply.

Comment: @TristenLee it's not substantially different to any other HV generator that uses a fast clock, whether CockroftWalton or inductive boost converter. You first need an FLC (Fairly Large Capacitor) on the output to provide initial bulk storage, which will give you a certain amount of ripple. If that's not small enough, you follow the cap with a filter, a regulator, or both. You do realise that 'low' is not a specification, 10 mV peak to peak (or whatever) is a specification. Once you have the high voltage, you engineer the noise and ripple to what is required.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not allergic to inductors, another approach would be to use a controller chip or a versatile chip such as the ubiquitous MC34063 with an external switch to boost the 12V to 100V.

Answer (score 1):

Is your 12v AC or DC? If AC a small transformer (50/60Hz) can do the job. If DC the DC/DC converter as you mention or charge pump.

Comment: It is a 12VDC source.